# C#　ゲームのようにリアルタイムでカーソルキーなどを取得したい

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

お世話になります。

表題から、かなり幼稚な質問だと思われてしまうと思いますが、お許しください。

C#(VCSExpress2015)を使用して、簡単なSTGを作ろうとしています。
要は、一番初めのキー操作でつまづいています。

但し、まったくできないわけではありません。
既存では、フォームにKeyDownとKeyUpのイベント実装させ、押したときと離したときの
操作をさせており、ここまででは問題なく作成できています。

問題は、このやり方ではなく、メインループの中でキー情報を取得したいのです。
自分でもサイトで調べましたが、GetKeyStateでできるということなので、
色々試しているのですが、コンパイルすら通らずにいます。

まず、System.Windows.Inputを参照し、続いてPresentationCode.dllを
追加しました。その後、メインループの中で、
   KeyStates kState = Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.Up);
という記述までできました。
その後、『IsKeyDown』というメソッドがあるらしいのですが、コードで記述しても
エラーになります。
ここからが解りません。

このやり方は、間違っているのでしょうか。

原因と対策をお教えください。

お願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: どのようなエラーメッセージが出力されているのでしょうか

Comment: 失礼しました。いつも文章が足らずに申し訳ありません。画像をアップしましたので、よろしくお願いします。ちなみに、この処理をメインループの中で行っています。

Comment: WinFormsとWPFを混在させるのは混乱のもとですのでお勧めしません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`は`static`メソッドですので、以下のように呼び出す必要があります。

```
Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Space)
```

なおキーが押されているか判定するのであれば、`GetKeyStates`と`IsKeyDown`はどちらか一方のみでよいです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。おかげで解決しました。これからも何卒よろしくお願いいたします。